# Google URL errors - soft 404s.

Tags: .htaccess

I've recently restructured my site and in the process have removed many pages.
I've put in .htaccess 301 redirects to reflect the changed structure where new pages directly replace old pages; have put in a custom 404 page and have included the following .htaccess command: ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html.
For pages removed altogether that have no new equivalent page, I've used .htaccess to redirect to the 'page not found' custom page.
In webmaster tools, though, I'm seeing soft 404s reported - pages not found that are not returning 404 response codes.
Can anybody please advise a way forward on this?
Should I not redirect references to the deleted pages and let the 'pages not found' stack up in the webmaster tools report, or is there a way of returning a 404 code from the server for my deleted pages even though a redirect exists?
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I think if the page doesn't have a new equivalent, then let it fall through not found, and return a 404 (which should show your custom page).

Google is showing a soft 404 because of the redirect (which is a 301, not a 404), as you say.

If you did redirect to the custom page, and somehow returned a 404, that's essentially the same thing as just letting them not be found.

The pages not found will stack up, but if they really aren't found anymore, then that's the correct response.

The alternative would be a 301 to a different page, that was a real "hey this moved, try this instead" page, but it would have to look like something other than "not found", to avoid google treating it as a soft 404.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. I was concerned in case having lots more 'pages not found' would effect Google rankings.

Comment: Glad this helped. If it did work for you, please consider accepting and voting my answer.